# Problemas com Paginação em php

Tags: php

Acabei de descobrir a falha. A url era a resposta!

O meu código estava mandando o endereço da seguinte forma:
localhost/portabilidades/pesquisas.php?pagina=2&seletor=solicitada

O que realmente mostrava os botões da numeração era este:
localhost/portabilidades/pesquisas.php?pagina=2&tipo=situacao&seletor=solicitada&filtro=

Então só precisei modificar na última linha que se refere a numeração para o equivalente como segue:

localhost/portabilidades/pesquisas.php?pagina=1&tipo=$situacao&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro

No script php:

```
//PAGINAÇAO
//Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior
$pagina_anterior = $pagina - 1;
$pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
print "<div class='container'>
<div>
                <ul class='pagination'>
                    <li>";
if($pagina_anterior != 0){
    print "<a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_anterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                            </a>";
}
else{
    print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>";
}
print "</li>";
//Apresentar a paginacao
for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){
    print"<li><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'>$i</a></li>";
}
print "<li>";
if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){
    print " <a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_posterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
            <span aria-hidden='true''>&raquo;</span>
        </a>";
}else{
    print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>";
}
print "</div></div>";
//FIM PAGINAÇAO
```

Fica a dica pra quem tiver a mesma dificuldade que eu tive.

Comment: Só para confirmar, nenhum dos botões da sua paginação funciona?

Comment: Opa, Obrigado pela pergunta amigo. Acabei de desvendar o mistério.

Comment: Só me confirma se era a falta de concatenação das url da paginaçao? haha

Comment: Foi mais falta de atenção mesmo. kkkkkkkkkk

Comment: kkkk certo, sucesso amigo, qualquer coisa estamos aqui!